# How to target last TD cell?

Tags: html, css, web

How do I make a specific TD not inherit CSS styles from the table?

[image]

How should I go about making the right most column not have any background at all?

```
table {
  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color:#666;
  font-size:12px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #fff;
  background:#eaebec;
  margin:20px;
  border:#ccc 1px solid;

  -moz-border-radius:3px;
  -webkit-border-radius:3px;
  border-radius:3px;

  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;
}
```

As it stands, the background #eaebec displays for the rightmost TD's as well, even though I set its background to transparent.

Appreciate all the help.

Comment: You really need to supply your html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`:last-of-type` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type) will help:

`#eaebec` is the table background.
You have two solutions,

#### Solution 1:

remove the background from table and do:

```
td{
    background: #eaebec;
}
td:last-of-type{
    background: none;
}
```

#### Solution 2:

simply style only the background of every last TD

```
td:last-of-type{
    background: #eaebec;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> As it stands, the background #eaebec displays for the rightmost td's as well, even though I set its background to transparent.

Your table has a background color, now if you make your td background color transparent, it makes the td transparent and what color do you expect transparent to have?? It just goes transparent and then when it's transparent you can see through and behind is the table which has a background color.

> How should I go about making the right most column not have any background at all?

In your scenario you can either set a desired background color to your last td. I mean the background color you expected for it to have after making it transparent.

> How do I make a specific td not inherit CSS styles from the table?

Also remember the td is not inheriting the CSS rules of the table as mentioned in your question.. td is just transparent and the background color we see is actually the table...